# Writing testable TypeScript classes for Dynamics CRM

Tags: typescript, testing, dependency-injection, dynamics-crm, crm

How do you write a class for a Dynamics CRM form in TypeScript that is testable?

By testable, I mean a non-static class that can be instantiated and passed a mock Xrm object.

My current approach is something like this, but it has limitations (which I explain):

```
export class Contact {
    Xrm: Xrm.XrmStatic;

    constructor(xrm?: Xrm.XrmStatic) {
        this.Xrm = xrm;
    }

    onLoad(): void {
       if (this.Xrm) { Xrm = this.Xrm; }
       // ...
    }
}
```

Firstly, the `Contact` class is exported so that can be referenced by a CRM form. CRM can't instantiate an object before calling it's functions, so to call these methods I use Contact.prototype.onLoad in the CRM form designer.

My test looks like this:

```
beforeEach(function () { 
    this.XrmMock = new XrmStaticMock();
    this.contact = new Contact(this.XrmMock);
    this.contact.onLoad();
}

it('does stuff', function () {
    // ...
}
```

The test is able to instantiate `Contact` and pass `XrmMock` to the constructor. Subsequently when `onLoad()` is called, it evaluates `if (this.Xrm)` to true, and uses `XrmMock`. Conversely, when `Contact.prototype.onLoad()` is called from within CRM, `(this.Xrm)` is false because `Contact` has never been instantiated. Therefore any reference to `Xrm` within `onLoad()` uses the default `Xrm` namespace (which is what we want). We want this because when a CRM form is opened, the real `Xrm` dependency is loaded by the browser.

The limitation here is having to write a conditional check in every method which wants to use the `Xrm` dependency. How can this be overcome?

Here's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328474.aspx) to documentation on the Xrm.Page object model. My classes and Xrm mock are written using [@types/xrm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/xrm).

---

I appreciate I'm asking multiple questions here, if you think you can guide me to writing a more specific question, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you call the `Contact.prototype.onLoad` method within CRM and not call a method that instantiates your Contact class in the same way as you do in your test but using CRM's `Xrm` object? E.g.

```
function ContactOnLoad() {
    var contact = new Contact(Xrm);
    contact.onLoad();
}
```

Then in your form's OnLoad handler you call `ContactOnLoad`. If you just call `Contact.prototype.onLoad`, `this` might refer to your window object and not a new instance of `Contact`.

Answer (score 0):

From J. Doe's answer I've arrived at code similar to as follows:

```
module Company.Contact {
    let contact: Contact;

    export function onLoad(xrm?: Xrm.XrmStatic) {
        contact = new Contact(xrm || Xrm);
        contact.onLoad();
    }

    export class Contact {
        constructor(xrm?: Xrm.XrmStatic) { Xrm = xrm || Xrm; }

        onLoad(): void {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

The solution is to create an exported function that is separate from the `Contact` object for each event you want to fire from CRM. The example above separates the `onLoad` method, but you could create functions for other CRM form events such as a field change:

```
module Company.Contact { 
    export function onLoad(xrm?: Xrm.XrmStatic) { // ... }
    export function firstNameOnChange() { // ... }    

    export class Contact { // ... }
}
```

You can also go one step further, and wrap the exported event functions in a module per entity form, such as Main and Mobile:

```
module Company.Contact { 
    export module MainForm {
        export function onLoad(xrm?: Xrm.XrmStatic) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    export module MobileForm {
        export function onLoad(xrm?: Xrm.XrmStatic) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    export class Contact { // ... }
}
```

### Usage in CRM

Just add `Company.Contact.onLoad` to the form or field's event handlers.

### Usage in tests

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // Create your Xrm mock from a separate mocking library
    this.XrmMock = new XrmStaticMock();

    // Call onLoad
    Company.Contact.onLoad(this.XrmMock);

    // Or use this if using separate modules per form
    Company.Contact.MainForm.onLoad(this.XrmMock);
}

describe('onLoad', () => {
    it('does stuff', () => {
        // ...
    }
}
```